# Why is currentView assigned to the wrong view?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an activity called Activity and this activity switches between View1 and View2 when a button clicks by setContentView() method.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.category_list);

    }
```

I want to switch to View1 when the BackButton on a device is pressed.

```
public void onBackPressed(){
        View currentView = this.findViewById(R.layout.product_list);
        if(currentView == findViewById(R.layout.category_list)){
            Log.i("VIEW1", "BACKBUTTON CLICKED ON VIEW1");

        } else if(currentView == findViewById(R.layout.product_list)) {
            Log.i("VIEW2", "BACKBUTTON CLICKED ON VIEW2");
        }
    }
```

Somehow everytime I click the back button on view2 the if statement for view1 is fired. The currentView becomes view1 while I had assigned it to view2. Why is this happening?

```
public void onClick(View view) {      

        setContentView(R.layout.product_list);          
    }
```

Comment: Make this global     `View currentView = this.findViewById(R.layout.product_list);` Everytime you click back button the `currentView ` get assigned.

Comment: obviously `findViewById` should not be used with `R.layout.xxx`

Comment: what do i use instead @Selvin

Comment: obviously `R.id.xxx`

Comment: When doing R.id the layout I want to switch to isnt showing up

Comment: I think, this is not the correct way to do. If you can tell the purpose, why you are doing like this then somebody will be able to give you better solution than yours@Darknax

Comment: `setContentView` expects to get `R.layout` and `findViewById` expects `R.id`

Comment: My purpose is clear. I have an activity and want to switch between layouts when clicking the previous button. @Selvin  read previous post

Comment: Use fragment with backstack

Comment: ... or store curent view resource in `int currentViewRes` after `setContentView`

Comment: @Darknax Use fragment instead. Here is the search result (https://www.google.co.in/search?q=two+fragments+in+an+activity+example&oq=two+fragments+in+an+activity+example&aqs=chrome..69i57j0.18080j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

Answer (score 0):

1. declare the View currentView in class level
2. set the value in onCreate

   ```
   currentView = this.findViewById(R.layout.category_list);
   ```
3. then

   ```
   public void onBackPressed(){;
        if(currentView == findViewById(R.layout.category_list)){
             Log.i("VIEW1", "BACKBUTTON CLICKED ON VIEW1");
             currentView = this.findViewById(R.layout.product_list);
         } else {
             Log.i("VIEW2", "BACKBUTTON CLICKED ON VIEW2");
             currentView = this.findViewById(R.layout.category_list);
         }
    }
   ```

Good luck

Comment: **`findViewById(R.layout.category_list)` will always return `null`** ... same story with `findViewById(R.layout.product_list)`

Comment: sorry i don't noticed, we should do it by id like:
             currentView = findViewById(R.id.category_list);
and we shoud set the id in the layout file to category_list like:
android:id="@+id/category_list" and the same for product_list